# How to call setState in flutter

Tags: flutter, state, setstate

Is this any essential difference how to call `setState` method using below code samples?

**1. Setting state variable inside setState**

```dart
setState((){
  _stateVariable1 = 'value1';
  _stateVariable2 = 'value2';
});
```

**2. Setting state variable outside setState**

```dart
_stateVariable1 = 'value1';
_stateVariable2 = 'value2';
setState((){});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is much of a difference other than;

Number 1 is the official endorsed way of showing what you want to perform a state change for.
Number 2 is how we newbies like to do it :)

Read up on in here,

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

Meaning that it does not matter if if is on the inside or not. everything is rebuild with your newly set variables.

> Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to
> wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might
> be associated with the change.

setState() is not able to handle future events it seems, they need to be awaited and finished before you can apply them in a setstate.

https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices

> When setState() is called on a State, all descendent widgets rebuild.
> Therefore, localize the setState() call to the part of the subtree
> whose UI actually needs to change. Avoid calling setState() high up in
> the tree if the change is contained to a small part of the tree.